# Getting error on SaveChanges while UpdateObject with early bound entities CRM SDK 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I am getting error on **xrm.saveChanges()** If I do **UpdateObject** while **AddObject** is working fine, initally I thought it is because of context as discussed in this thread [Dynamics CRM saving Entity Changes - Getting Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216396/dynamics-crm-saving-entity-changes-getting-errors)
but I tried all the options discussed here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695783.aspx but nothing helped out.

My code is `

```
        using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm"))
        {
            WriteExampleContacts(xrm);

            //Create a new contact called Allison Brown.
            var allisonBrown = new Xrm.Contact
            {
                FirstName = "Allison",
                LastName = "Brown",
                Address1_Line1 = "23 Market St.",
                Address1_City = "Sammamish",
                Address1_StateOrProvince = "MT",
                Address1_PostalCode = "99999",
                Telephone1 = "12345678",
                EMailAddress1 = "allison.brown@example.com"
            };

            xrm.AddObject(allisonBrown);
            xrm.SaveChanges();

            WriteExampleContacts(xrm);



        //Update the e-mail address of Allison Brown and link her to the account Contoso.

        //allisonBrown.contact_customer_accountsParentCustomerAccount = account;
        using (var xrm2 = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm"))
        {

            xrm.Detach(allisonBrown);
            xrm2.Attach(allisonBrown);


            allisonBrown.EMailAddress1 = "allison.brown@contoso.com";
            xrm2.UpdateObject(allisonBrown);
            xrm2.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Update the contact record and then commit the changes to Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use all contacts where the email address ends in @example.com.
    /// </summary>
    private static void WriteExampleContacts(XrmServiceContext xrm)
    {
        var exampleContacts = xrm.ContactSet
            .Where(c => c.EMailAddress1.EndsWith("@example.com"));

        //Write the example contacts.
        foreach (var contact in exampleContacts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contact.FullName);
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is

```
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occured while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges()
       at MuslimAidConsoleApplication.Sample.Main(String[] args)           at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 12522. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts:ConcurrencyBehavior'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'ConcurrencyBehavior' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
       Source=mscorlib
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you creating another Context?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and start happening when I updated to CRM SDK 2015 I found this link but Im still unable to make it work https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5abb9b69-bec2-41fd-aa13-d8c2c22a162c/whats-wrong-with-a-simple-fetchxml-statement?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: Have you reached anything ?
same problem here !
would you mind sharing your results?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this version...
It's working for me...

SDK Version 7.0.a
October 2014

http://www.filedropper.com/microsoftdynamicscrm2015sdk

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable early bound entities by calling

```
_serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
```

on your OrganizationServiceProxy instance.

```
var cred = new ClientCredentials();
cred.UserName.UserName = "your username";
cred.UserName.Password = "your password";
using (var _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("https://[your organization service url here]"), null, cred, null))
{
    _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes(); // Will throw error on save changes if not here
    var context = new CrmServiceContext(_serviceProxy);

    context.AddObject(new Opportunity() { Name = "My opportunity" });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating the proxy types should solve the issue.

Also, since you're Online, make sure you have the latest version of the SDK (no need to hunt them down, they're available on NuGet).